# What is .tpl.html files? (angularjs)

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm doing a angularjs blog tutorial, in the code example I see this new file type "**tpl.html**":

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
templateUrl: 'views/post-list.tpl.html',
controller: 'PostListController',
controllerAs: 'postlist'
})
.when('/post/:postId', {
templateUrl: 'views/post-detail.tpl.html',
controller: 'PostDetailController',
controllerAs: 'postdetail'
})
.when('/new', {
templateUrl: 'views/post-create.tpl.html',
controller: 'PostCreateController',
controllerAs: 'postcreate'
});
```

What is this file type? Is different to html files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Theoretically, the "file type" is just a part of the file name. I can make a file called `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.html` and it is just as valid a file name as any other. But e.g. the modern OS's treat the stuff after the last period as the "file type", which helps in launching the right programs etc. So a `a.tpl.html` would be an HTML file just as any other. The `.tpl` is just something that helps to recognize what the file is used for.

Simply put, file names can contain more than one period, and it's still just a part of the name, nothing special there. And whatever comes after the very last period would be treated as the "file type".

Comment: You didnt answer what "tpl" in the file name means

Answer (score 6):

It is just a little helper added by the author to mark these files as templates. This could be helpful when you see these files not in context - e.g. in the file system. You can name these html files how you like it! :)

Comment: what sort of template? your answer could be more helpful if it was specific

Answer (score 5):

The .tpl file extension is used by a template parser called Smarty. This is an HTML template parser.
Developers append .html to the end of the file so they can be recognized by text editors as HTML file and provide syntax checking, intellisense, and stuff.